# postgres constraint on one table according to data in another table

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with 2 tables, `foo` and `foo_trash`.

Both have the same structure with an `id` (primary key), and a `title`. foo_trash gets populated with data copied from foo with a statement like this:

`INSERT INTO foo_trash (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 253)`

I would like to add a `constraint` on the table foo_trash so that no rows may be inserted into foo_trash if the same pair id and title is not present in foo.

How do I write that?

Comment: Use a foreign key constraint.

Comment: add a foreign key to the foo_trash table foo_id? That wouldn't work because of the manner of adding data to the foo_trash.

Comment: "*How do I do that?*" - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK

Comment: "*That wouldn't work because of the manner of adding data to the foo_trash*" - why?

Comment: Because then the number of rows in the table `foo` and `foo_trash` would not be the same. So the instruction insert into `foo_trash` everything you select from a row in `foo` can be executed since `foo` doesn't have a column `foo_id`.

Comment: "*Then the number of rows in the table foo and foo_trash would not be the same*" - you mean columns not rows? But I did not say to add a new column `foo_id`, I did say to add a constraint.

Comment: Yes columns. Sorry. So something along the lines in the `foo_trash` table of `FOREIGN KEY (id, title) REFERENCES foo (id, title)` ?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE foo_trash ADD CONSTRAINT fk_foo FOREIGN KEY (id, title) REFERENCES foo (id, title) ON DELETE CASCADE, ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the table foo:

```
create table foo (
  id int,
  title varchar(50),
  primary key (id, title)
  );
```

Define the table foo_trash to reference the two columns you mentioned:

```
create table foo_trash (
  id int primary key,
  title varchar(50),
  FOREIGN KEY (id, title) REFERENCES foo (id, title)
  );
```

Now you can insert data into foo:

```
insert into foo values (1, 'title1');
insert into foo values (2, 'title2');
insert into foo values (3, 'title3');
insert into foo values (253, 'title253');
```

If you try to insert a row into foo_trash that doesn't exist in foo, you will receive an error:

```
insert into foo_trash values (4, 'title4');
```

Output:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "foo_trash" violates foreign key constraint "foo_trash_id_title_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id, title)=(4, title4) is not present in table "foo".
```

You can insert a row in foo_trash that exists in foo:

```
insert into foo_trash values (3, 'title3');
```

And you can do your insert into foo_trash as select from foo successfully, assuming that id exists:

```
INSERT INTO foo_trash (SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 253);
```